# How to specify config file for building buildroot?

Tags: c, makefile, kernel, buildroot, kconfig

I downloaded buildroot package and tried to build using a config file under /configs directory such as raspberrypi3_64_defconfig.

If I run make menuconfig, menuconfig screen loads a default config.
If I copy the raspberrypi3_64_defconfig under /buildroot and change the name to .config and run make menuconfig, then I can see the configs for raspberrypi3_64.

Is there any way I can specify the raspberrypi3_64_defconfig when I run make menuconfig without copying the file and renaming it?

Answer (score 3):

`make raspberrypi3_64_defconfig` is what you need

Comment: I think make raspberryi3_64_defconfig just create .config file. Maybe my questions was not clear. What I wanted was there was any command option I can go to make menuconfig screen directly with configuration from raspberry3_64_defconfig enabled.

Comment: "make menuconfig" will only ever show the configuration described in the .config file. So indeed you have to run "make raspberrypi3_64_defconfig" first to create a new .config using the raspberrypi3_64_defconfig configuration as a starting point, and from this point you can use "make menuconfig" to tune your configuration. Nothing Buildroot specific here, the Linux kernel configuration system works in exactly the same way.